# Codeigniter echo session Multidimensional Array variable

Tags: codeigniter, session, multidimensional-array

Okay im using codeigniter and i got a session where i want to echo [user_id], i can see its an "Multidimensional Array", but i cant seem to get it right...

This is the print_r from all session userdata:

```
Array ( 
[session_id] => b7e721332248 
[ip_address] => ::1 
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 
[last_activity] => 1409104940 
[user_data] => [name] => 2 [uniq] => 2 
[flexi_auth] => Array ( [user_identifier] => mail.com [user_id] => 2 [admin] => 1 
[group] => Array ( [3] => Master Admin ) 
[privileges] => Array ( ) 
[logged_in_via_password] => 1 
[login_session_token] => 11017021313jhbjh1h2j3b213mab913269d95 ) )
```

if i type:

1. `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` // i will get all
2. `echo $this->session->userdata('uniq');` //returns 2
3. `echo $this->session->userdata('user_id');` //returns nothing(THIS IS THE PROBLEM)

Ive tried something like this:
`$this->session->userdata(1,1);` //1,1 would be array 2 and number 2 which would be user_id

Is it because i can only print out if I loop through them somehow?

Comment: How are you setting the session data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call the data directly, if you're want to access `user_data` or `flexi_auth` you need to assign the data to a variable then target it since they're arrays.

```
$session_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
echo $session_data['user_data']['uniq']; // 2

$user_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
echo $user_data['uniq']; /// 2

$flexi_auth = $this->session->userdata('flexi_auth');
echo $flexi_auth['user_id']; /// 2
```

If you're trying to target a string directly

```
echo $this->session->userdata('last_activity');
```

Comment: $flexi_auth = $this->session->userdata('flexi_auth');
echo $flexi_auth['user_id']; //this is it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access user name stored in session like this

```
echo $this->session->userdata['user_data']['name'];
```

Be sure you have some userdata in session or use like this to avoid any errors

```
echo @$this->session->userdata['user_data']['name'];
```

adding @ does not generate any errors. hope you got the answer you were looking for.